# What Backgrounds would be reasonable for a shovelhead?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Each character gets 5 Background points upon character generation. As far as I remember, one can't just convert them into freebie points to use onto something else. However, I can't find any reasonable way for a shovelhead to have any of them upon Embrace, except probably Generation, as he loses all he had from his life as a mortal. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an optional rule on page 85 of the V20 Core Book, in the box called "More Inhuman Vampires". Shovelheads get 4 Discipline dots upon the Embrace instead of 3, which makes them very dangerous for Camarilla neonates, especially when paired with their huge quantity.

Comment: Just forgot that, looked at the book and found the answer right away, but something made want to post this.